# Matrix Multiplication React

Tags: reactjs, matrix, matrix-multiplication

These are two Matrix I want to multipy

```
array1 : [
      [1,2,3,4,5],
      [1,2,3,4,5],
      [1,2,3,4,5],
      [1,2,3,4,5]
    ],
    array2 : [
      [1,2,3],
      [1,2,3],
      [1,2,3],
      [1,2,3],
      [1,2,3]],
```

The logic for my multiplication is not working
this is the logic

```
let arr=[];
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
let row =[];
for(let j = 0; j < 3; j++){
  let col =[];
  for(let k= 0; k < 5 ; k++){
let result = this.state.array1[i][k]*this.state.array2[j][k]
col.push(result);  
}
row.push(col)
}
arr.push(row)
return arr;
```

The result I am getting is

```
[1, 4, 9, NaN, NaN]
[1, 4, 9, NaN, NaN]
[1, 4, 9, NaN, NaN]
```

which is not the correct answer.
I believe my logic is wrong. If anyone can help with this. it will be appreciated.
TIA

Comment: Why are you tagging reactjs in this question?

Comment: What are expected results ? What are rules for the different sizes?

Comment: Because I am making this on react

Comment: The expected Result is 
[15    30      45]
[15    30      45]                                                                                                               [15    30      45]                                                                                                            [15    30      45]

Comment: The rule is that the Row1 of array1 get multiplied by all the columns of array2         then the second row is multiplied with all columns and then the third and then 4